# RESTful way to return server hostname and port

Tags: rest, http, header, server, hostname

Imagine I have a RESTful service which is deployed on multiple hosts, and not necessarily use the same port number. There is a loadbalancer/proxy/gateway on a separate host. I want hostname and ip address to be returned as part of http response to have a diagnostic info regarding the actual physical server that has processed my request (not loadbalancer). What's the most RESTful way to return this kind of information? Are there any special http headers that should be used for this purpose, or is it better just to return this data as part of diagnostic info section within response body (e.g. json)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the HTTP Header 'Location' could be useful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Comment: This article says that it should be used only for redirection, or for newly created resource (which is not usually performed using GET http verb). Neither of these two are my cases because I want to send simple GET requests.

Comment: OK. It sounds like what you need is a custom HTTP Header rather than adding server info to the response sent to the client. Unless the client needs the server info for its next request?

Comment: No, it should not be used for next request. The purpose of this information is purely diagnostic, so it is supposed to be used for troubleshooting only. My concern regarding adding a custom header is that it does not fit well into one of the fundamental REST principles - uniform interface. Clients will have no information about the semantics of this header because it is not widely used, whereas a dedicated json section in response body can be well defined and self-described by the means of HATEOAS.

Comment: How about just logging requests then?